# Identifier has already been declared error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error when using sample code from the up and going book in the ydkjs series. Can anyone help me out? The error is

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ACCESSORY_PRICE' has already been declared
    at :1:1

```
const ACCESSORY_PRICE = 9.99;
var bank_balance = 302.13;
var amount = 99.99;

amount = amount * 2;

// can we afford the extra purchase?
if ( amount < bank_balance ) {
    console.log( "I'll take the accessory!" );
    amount = amount + ACCESSORY_PRICE;
}
// otherwise:
else {
    console.log( "No, thanks." );
}
```

Comment: Shared code seems incomplete considering the mentioned error!

Comment: it works as is written.

Comment: You're declaring your `ACCESSORY_PRICE` more than once in your code

Comment: This code as you posted is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4m1n29tL/ please post the code with the error you mentioned.

Comment: Did you type this in the console, run it and than run it again? IN that case the first variable declaration was already there so you now have the error.

Answer (score 4):

You are using an environment where executing the very same code **twice** (or more) doesn't allow you to redeclare already declared consts.

I can easily reproduce the code in Chrome's console, in the Sources/Snippets section. Executing the code for the first time works as expected. Executing it again raises the error as the const is already defined by the prior execution.

Assuming the Chrome's console (or similar) is your environment, one of the workarounds is to hit F5 to refresh the page under the console and rerun the script.

Another, disputably cleaner workaround is to switch to another environment where mutliple executions of the same code have no such unexpected effects.

Comment: Clever answer to the missing information in the question ;)

Comment: Upvoted. And I learned another trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-declare a `const`. This error says you already declared `ACCESSORY_PRICE`. Remove the second `const ACCESSORY_PRICE` or `var ACCESSORY_PRICE` or `let ACCESSORY_PRICE`.

Comment: But there's no other declaration. And it's code is working fine. Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/4m1n29tL/